# Поиск коинтеграции на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, статистика

Из файла txt берутся тикеры акций. Нужно посчитать коэффициент ковариации, например для AAPL и TXN он получился 0,74. А когда приписал брать акции из одного файла, вместо двух разных S1, S2, то работать отказывается. Как заставить его считать коэффициент для всех акций из txt?

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import datetime
import numpy as np

import statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import coint

from datetime import date
from pandas_datareader import data

symbols_fn = r'C:\Temp\.data\631336\symbols.txt'
with open(symbols_fn) as f:
    stocklist = f.read().splitlines()

start = '2016-01-01'
end = '2016-12-31'

S1, S2 = wb.DataReader(stocklist, 'yahoo', start, end)

result = coint(S1[['Close']], S2[['Close']])
score = result[0]
pvalue = result[1]

score, pvalue, _ = coint(S1[['Close']], S2[['Close']])
print(pvalue)
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял исходный код `statsmodel.tsa.stattools.coint` - он ожидает на вход векторы (1D arrays), т.е. скормить этой функции сразу много инструментов не получится. Наверное придется писать цикл и считать попарно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller, coint
from itertools import combinations

# read up financial data ('Close') for all tickers
symbols_fn = r'D:\download\9017879_symbol.txt'
with open(symbols_fn) as f:
    stocklist = f.read().splitlines()

start = '2016-01-01'
end = '2016-12-31'

x = wb.DataReader(stocklist, 'yahoo', start, end).loc['Close']

# generate pairs (combinations of pairs for all tickers)
pairs = list(combinations(x.columns.tolist(), 2))

data = []

# calculate cointegrations for each pair of tickers
for a,b in pairs:
    data.append(coint(x[a], x[b]))

# build a Pandas.DataFrame based on the result of cointegration
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=['coint_t','pvalue','crit_value'],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(pairs, names=['a', 'b'])
)
```

Результат:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
            coint_t    pvalue                                        crit_value
a    b
AAPL ADI  -2.399547  0.325069  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     ADM  -1.766708  0.645747  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     ADP  -1.714724  0.670144  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     ADSK -2.441990  0.305234  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     AIV  -1.658111  0.695751  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     AIZ  -1.730617  0.662771  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     AJG  -1.850511  0.604879  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     AMAT -2.350225  0.348777  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     AN   -1.526342  0.750953  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     ANTM -1.211491  0.854866  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
...             ...       ...                                               ...
BHI  BK   -3.528199  0.029976  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     BLL  -1.032398  0.896528  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     T    -0.587248  0.957508  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     TXN  -1.805689  0.626955  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
BK   BLL  -1.144756  0.871779  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     T    -0.954469  0.911148  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     TXN  -1.838958  0.610613  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
BLL  T    -1.960588  0.548994  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     TXN  -2.924919  0.129148  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
T    TXN  -1.891437  0.584344  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]

[465 rows x 3 columns]
```

**UPDATE:**   результаты для трех инструментов: `['AAPL', 'AME', 'GOOG']`:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
            coint_t    pvalue                                        crit_value
a    b
AAPL AME  -1.310313  0.826602  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
     GOOG -4.043216  0.006225  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
AME  GOOG -3.734957  0.016513  [-3.45656889661, -2.87307861944, -2.57291899534]
```

Проверка:

```
In [13]: coint(x['AAPL'], x['AME'])
Out[13]:
(-1.3103131127615668,
 0.82660200322788824,
 array([-3.4565689 , -2.87307862, -2.572919  ]))

In [14]: coint(x['AAPL'], x['GOOG'])
Out[14]:
(-4.0432156294166424,
 0.0062253442468271384,
 array([-3.4565689 , -2.87307862, -2.572919  ]))

In [15]: coint(x['AME'], x['GOOG'])
Out[15]:
(-3.734956880459813,
 0.016513005631255184,
 array([-3.4565689 , -2.87307862, -2.572919  ]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Данные:

```
x = wb.DataReader(stocklist, 'yahoo', start='1/1/2016', end='1/12/2016').loc['Close']

In [50]: x
Out[50]:
                  AAPL        AME        GOOG
Date
2016-01-04  105.349998  52.650002  741.840027
2016-01-05  102.709999  52.380001  742.580017
2016-01-06  100.699997  51.189999  743.619995
2016-01-07   96.449997  49.980000  726.390015
2016-01-08   96.959999  49.070000  714.469971
2016-01-11   98.529999  48.200001  716.030029
2016-01-12   99.959999  48.470001  726.070007
```

Решение:

```
In [51]: # generate pairs (combinations of pairs for all tickers)
    ...: pairs = list(combinations(x.columns.tolist(), 2))
    ...:
    ...: data = []
    ...:
    ...: # calculate cointegrations for each pair of tickers
    ...: for a,b in pairs:
    ...:     data.append(coint(x[a], x[b]))
    ...:
    ...: # build a Pandas.DataFrame based on the result of cointegration
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     data,
    ...:     columns=['coint_t','pvalue','crit_value'],
    ...:     index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(pairs, names=['a', 'b'])
    ...: )
    ...:
```

Результат:

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]:
            coint_t    pvalue                                        crit_value
a    b
AAPL AME  -1.303168  0.828778  [-4.93869023324, -3.47758285714, -2.84386795918]
     GOOG -2.012823  0.521906  [-4.93869023324, -3.47758285714, -2.84386795918]
AME  GOOG -1.420313  0.790466  [-4.93869023324, -3.47758285714, -2.84386795918]
```

Сравним:

```
In [53]: coint(y1, x1)
Out[53]:
(-1.4203126278701015,
 0.79046585398440861,
 array([-4.93869023, -3.47758286, -2.84386796]))
```